# Reproducing a Ganache Server across multiple computers

Tags: truffle, accounts, ganache, ganache-cli

There are multiple developers on the team and it seems as though we all want to be working on a specific *test* network with specific public and private keys with a specific number of users who all have a prespecified balance. We have chosen to work with **Ganache**.

Now I am aware of [https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cl](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli)i options with `--account=`. This does not allow for the specification of the public key of each user. What is the standard when recreating a network? Am I missing out on something fundamental to this process? What are my options?

Comment: `This does not allow for the specification of the public key of each user` - no, but it allows for the specification of the private key of each user, and the public key derives from that in a (pretty much) one-to-one way.

Comment: pretty one to one way? Is that 100% correct? Do I need to modify the pneumonic to comply with this one to one mapping?

Comment: What???? Ganache creates unique accounts according to unique private keys that you provide using the `--account` option. What more do you want???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ganache-cli, you can provide a mnemonic using the flag below, in order to produce the same pre-funded addresses and public keys every time you start ganache. The accounts flag just defines the number of accounts that you will create.

> -m or --mnemonic: Use a bip39 mnemonic phrase for generating a PRNG seed, which is in turn used for hierarchical deterministic (HD)
> account generation.

Per the comments - the addresses and private keys generated will be one to one regardless of the mnemonic.